# I cannot manage a RBAC role on a Azure resource with Privileged Identity Management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'am a permanent member of the RBAC role "User Access Admin" on a resource in Azure. But when I try to access the resource from Azure AD PIM, I get a 403 error.

I can access and manage permissions the resource in the portal via IAM and I have the correct license.

Why doesn't PIM let me manage the resource?

Regards,
Carl

Comment: Azure roles are different than Azure AD roles. Can you check your roles in Azure AD?

Answer (score 1):

The [`User Access Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) belongs to the [Azure RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) which are used to manage the Azure resources in the subscription, if you have this role, you can manage the role assignments in `Access control (IAM)` of the subscription/resource directly.

Privileged Identity Management(PIM) is a feature of Azure AD, even it can also be used to manage the role assignments in subscription, to use it e.g. Assign users to roles, you need the [Azure AD admin roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference) which are different from Azure RBAC roles, in this case, at least you need [`Privileged role administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#privileged-role-administrator), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-by-task#privileged-identity-management).

To give an Azure AD admin role to a user, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal).